# Can a GPU be shared among multiple cores of a CPU?

Tags: mpi, cpu, gpgpu

I have an application in which each CPU core does a number of matrix multiplications. The number of matrix multiplications may be in the order of 10s, e.g. 50. Since these multiplications are independent of each other, the core could offload them to a GPU. Now, I have several such cores being used by an MPI program. So, my question is, is it possible at all to share the GPU among these multiple cores, so each core could offload the matrix multiplications to the same GPU?

Comment: In theory, yes, but then the GPU might become the bottleneck...

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will check it out.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible, and unless your GPU code is already highly optimized internally, this usually is a simple way of increasing utilization of your GPU. But each process requires a separate GPU context, which has considerable memory overhead, and it isn't possible to create a shared mempool across these different processes (or at least it will be a massive pain). If memory is at all limiting, this is far from optimal.

So if memory is no concern, this is probably the most straightforward method to increase GPU utilization. However, I find it generally cleaner to use one process per GPU, and then farm out independent tasks using one thread/coroutine per GPU stream.

Answer (score 1):

For Nvidia GPUs this feature is called Multi-process service (MPS). You have to start a server on your machine that handles the GPU requests from all of your MPI ranks and passes them to the single GPU. The command is nvidia-cuda-mps-control. It's described here. https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/pdf/CUDA_Multi_Process_Service_Overview.pdf.